# How to remove all parent nodes if a child node value contains a specific string using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document where if the emailAddress tag contains '@test' then the entire User and  its child nodes need to be deleted.

Here is the XML.

```
<Users>
    <User>
        <empInfo>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <personNav>
                    <PerPerson>
                        <personalInfoNav>
                            <PerPersonal>
                                <firstName>Gr</firstName>
                                <lastName>Coll</lastName>
                                <secondLastName>Gre</secondLastName>
                                <middleName>M</middleName>
                                <thirdName>Cos</thirdName>
                            </PerPersonal>
                        </personalInfoNav>
                        <customString1>NetID6</customString1>
                        <personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
                            <PersonEmpTerminationInfo>
                                <latestTerminationDate/>
                            </PersonEmpTerminationInfo>
                        </personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
                        <phoneNav>
                            <PerPhone>
                                <phoneType>5892</phoneType>
                                <extension/>
                                <phoneNumber>4882928200</phoneNumber>
                                <isPrimary>true</isPrimary>
                                <phoneTypeNav>
                                    <PicklistOption>
                                        <externalCode>B</externalCode>
                                        <localeLabel>Business Mobile</localeLabel>
                                    </PicklistOption>
                                </phoneTypeNav>
                            </PerPhone>
                        </phoneNav>
                        <emailNav>
                            <PerEmail>
                                <emailAddress>noreply@test.com.au</emailAddress>
                                <emailTypeNav>
                                    <PicklistOption>
                                        <externalCode>B</externalCode>
                                        <localeLabel>Business</localeLabel>
                                    </PicklistOption>
                                </emailTypeNav>
                                <emailType>5877</emailType>
                                <isPrimary>true</isPrimary>
                            </PerEmail>
                        </emailNav>
                    </PerPerson>
                </personNav>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </empInfo>
    </User>
    <User>
        <empInfo>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <personNav>
                    <PerPerson>
                        <personalInfoNav>
                            <PerPersonal>
                                <firstName>Gr</firstName>
                                <lastName>Coll</lastName>
                                <secondLastName>Gre</secondLastName>
                                <middleName>M</middleName>
                                <thirdName>Cos</thirdName>
                            </PerPersonal>
                        </personalInfoNav>
                        <customString1>NetID6</customString1>
                        <personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
                            <PersonEmpTerminationInfo>
                                <latestTerminationDate/>
                            </PersonEmpTerminationInfo>
                        </personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
                        <phoneNav>
                            <PerPhone>
                                <phoneType>5892</phoneType>
                                <extension/>
                                <phoneNumber>4882928200</phoneNumber>
                                <isPrimary>true</isPrimary>
                                <phoneTypeNav>
                                    <PicklistOption>
                                        <externalCode>B</externalCode>
                                        <localeLabel>Business Mobile</localeLabel>
                                    </PicklistOption>
                                </phoneTypeNav>
                            </PerPhone>
                        </phoneNav>
                        <emailNav>
                            <PerEmail>
                                <emailAddress>noreply@wa.com.au</emailAddress>
                                <emailTypeNav>
                                    <PicklistOption>
                                        <externalCode>B</externalCode>
                                        <localeLabel>Business</localeLabel>
                                    </PicklistOption>
                                </emailTypeNav>
                                <emailType>5877</emailType>
                                <isPrimary>true</isPrimary>
                            </PerEmail>
                        </emailNav>
                    </PerPerson>
                </personNav>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </empInfo>
    </User>
</Users>
```

This XSLT transformation does this but only works on the entire string in the emailAddress tag, how can I get it to work only if the string contains specific text inside it?

Here is the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="User[not(.//emailAddress = 'noreply@test.com.au')]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output

```
<Users>
    <User>
        <empInfo>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <personNav>
                    <PerPerson>
                        <personalInfoNav>
                            <PerPersonal>
                                <firstName>Gr</firstName>
                                <lastName>Coll</lastName>
                                <secondLastName>Gre</secondLastName>
                                <middleName>M</middleName>
                                <thirdName>Cos</thirdName>
                            </PerPersonal>
                        </personalInfoNav>
                        <customString1>NetID6</customString1>
                        <personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
                            <PersonEmpTerminationInfo>
                                <latestTerminationDate/>
                            </PersonEmpTerminationInfo>
                        </personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
                        <phoneNav>
                            <PerPhone>
                                <phoneType>5892</phoneType>
                                <extension/>
                                <phoneNumber>4882928200</phoneNumber>
                                <isPrimary>true</isPrimary>
                                <phoneTypeNav>
                                    <PicklistOption>
                                        <externalCode>B</externalCode>
                                        <localeLabel>Business Mobile</localeLabel>
                                    </PicklistOption>
                                </phoneTypeNav>
                            </PerPhone>
                        </phoneNav>
                        <emailNav>
                            <PerEmail>
                                <emailAddress>noreply@test.com.au</emailAddress>
                                <emailTypeNav>
                                    <PicklistOption>
                                        <externalCode>B</externalCode>
                                        <localeLabel>Business</localeLabel>
                                    </PicklistOption>
                                </emailTypeNav>
                                <emailType>5877</emailType>
                                <isPrimary>true</isPrimary>
                            </PerEmail>
                        </emailNav>
                    </PerPerson>
                </personNav>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </empInfo>
    </User>
</Users>
```

Comment: Your xslt seems to look ok.  Are there namespaces being used?

Comment: You say you want to remove User if emailAddress contains '@test'  - but you're showing and doing (or rather attempting to do) the exact opposite.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: correct. Just remove the not()

Answer (score 0):

> This XSLT transformation does this but only works on the entire string
> in the emailAddress tag, how can I get it to work only if the string
> contains specific text inside it?

Try changing this…

```xml
<xsl:template match="User[not(.//emailAddress = 'noreply@test.com.au')]" />
```

to this…

```xml
<xsl:template match="User[not(.//emailAddress[contains(.,'@test')]]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete that node() you should use the contains function and remove the not(), because then all these nodes will fall in that match doing nothing and therefore being deleted.

```
<xsl:template match="User[.//emailAddress[contains(.,'@test']]" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?